# Cost calculation and finding the big O notaion

Tags: python, algorithm, big-o

When calculating the cost to identify the Big O notation of this code, should I count following line too?

if(n == 0):
print("Incorrect index No ")

if yes how to connect it with the loop

```
def FindFibonacci(n):
    

    if(n == 0):
        print("Incorrect index No ")
        
           
    else:
        
        n1 = 0
        n2 = 1
        x = 0
        while (x<n):
            print(n1)
            fib = n1 + n2
            n1 = n2
            n2 = fib

            x = x+1
            
num = int(input("How many Fibonacci sequences you want? "))  

FindFibonacci(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when calculating the cost to identify the Big O notation of this code, you should also take the following line into account:

```
if(n == 0):
    print("Incorrect index No ")
```

It is not customary to include `print` statements in a function of which you want to identify the time complexity, but since the output string has a constant number of characters, we may assume it executes in O(1).

> how to connect it with the loop?

The evaluation of the `if` condition (`n == 0`) has O(1) time complexity. When that condition is true, the `print` statement adds O(1) time complexity and the loop is not executed. So the overall time complexity for that particular case is O(1 + 1) = O(1).

For the case where the `if` condition is not true, the loop gets executed, so you need to find out what the loop's time complexity is. You'll find it is O(n). So in total you have O(1 + n) which still is O(n).

Taking all cases together -- including where n is 0 -- we get O(1 + n) which is O(n).

Comment: Just a minor technical detail: to combine the complexities of the two branches of the selection, I would rather write max(1, n), though O(max(1, n)) and O(1 + n) are indeed equivalent.

Comment: My reasoning was that O(1 + 0) for the first case just fits nicely with O(1 + n), since indeed in the first case n is zero. But it doesn't matter as it comes down to the same thing.

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped me to understand the situation. This is for an assignment. I have to list the cost and number of times to each step. I will have this separately, if the condition is true and false. Thanks again!

Comment: On second thoughts, discussing the asymtotic complexity when n=0 does not make sense at all. Returning to the definition of Big-O, we take n≥N0>0 and strictly ignore the case of n=0.

Answer (score 0):

Let us recall that

`f(n) = O(g(n))` if there are constants `c` and `N` such that for all `n≥N`, `|f(n)|≤g(n)`.

So one can safely ignore all special cases arising below some bounded value, and here the case of `n=0` is quite irrelevant (you don't even evaluate its cost).

Other example:

```
if n < 1000 then print(n!) else print('Overflow')
```

has complexity `O(1)`.

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped a lot. I will state this separately in my assignment.

Comment: Sorry, my answer was not satisfactory to my eyes. Completely rewritten.